# Ace Combat 6 Flight Stick And XboxDrv

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to get my [Xbox 360 USB Flight Stick](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Ace_Combat_6_-_Ace_Edge.jpg) to connect to the Raspberry Pi.

So far, dmesg confirms that it connects, but then it just flashes. Xboxdrv doesn't register anything being connected.

I have tested the stick on other non-pi machines, and they have all seen, recognized and utilized the stick. I read it could be due to the power requirement for a wired controller.

Has anyone else gotten this to connect successfully?

using Raspbian and PiMAME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stick might need a good powered USB hub. Try one with dedicated power ports which shall guaranty adequate power being delivered to your device.

[For example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009Z9M3DY)) :
[image]